# Properly Index an UNPIVOT SQL query

Tags: sql-server, indexing, query-optimization

If I had a table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    StudentName VARCHAR (50),
    Math INT,
    English INT,
    History INT,
    Science INT
)
GO
```

and an `unpivot` query such as:

```
SELECT StudentName, Course, Score
FROM Students
UNPIVOT
(
    Score
    FOR Course in (Math, English, History, Science)
) AS SchoolUnpivot
```

What would an optimal index look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I populated 1.000.000 test data into **Students** table and then I started to test the following queries;

**Note** Don't use the  `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` statment in the production environment.

**Test environment :**

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RC1) - 15.0.1900.25 (X64)   Aug 16 2019
>   14:20:53   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 17763: )

**Test-1:**

The following query takes **34 seconds**.

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
 SELECT StudentName, Course, Score
FROM Students
 CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES 
        ('Math', Math),
        ('English', English),
        ('History', History),
        ('Science', Science)
    ) x(Course, Score)
WHERE Score IS NOT NULL

OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

**Test-2:**
The following query takes **40 seconds**.

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
 SELECT StudentName, Course, Score
FROM Students
 CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES 
        ('Math', Math),
        ('English', English),
        ('History', History),
        ('Science', Science)
    ) x(Course, Score)
WHERE Score IS NOT NULL

OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

**Test-3:**

The following query takes **32seconds** after the creation of the index , also the execution plan  uses the created index in the execution plan.

```
   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [PerformanceIndex] ON [dbo].[Students]
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [Math] ASC,
    [English] ASC,
    [History] ASC,
    [Science] ASC
)
INCLUDE([StudentName])
GO
 DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
 GO
SELECT StudentName, Course, Score
FROM Students
UNPIVOT
(
    Score
    FOR Course in (Math, English, History, Science)
) AS SchoolUnpivo

OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

**As a result**, using the unpivot columns in the nonclustered index helps us to improve the query performance particularly for this case.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I as looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure which indexes could be used to optimize the query. One would need to have a look at the execution plan of the query to make an educated suggestion.

But before you go for indexing, you can try and optimize the query. One option to speed up performance would to use `CROSS APPLY VALUES` instead of `UNPIVOT` . The [following blog article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/an-alternative-better-method-to-unpivot-sql-spackle) goes into great details on the performance improvement it could provide.

Hence, consider the following query:

```
SELECT StudentName, Course, Score
FROM Students
 CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES 
        ('Math', Math),
        ('English', English),
        ('History', History),
        ('Science', Science)
    ) x(Course, Score)
WHERE Score IS NOT NULL
```

I am curious to know if you get the same performance benefit the blog author reported.